# How do I GROUP BY Combination of column in SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Suppose I have a table like below,

```
Date         |Student ID| Building 
2019-01-01   | 1        |    A
2019-01-01   | 1        |    B
2019-01-01   | 1        |    C
2019-01-01   | 2        |    B
2019-01-01   | 2        |    C
2019-01-01   | 3        |    C
2019-01-01   | 3        |    B
2019-01-01   | 4        |    B
```

How do I group by unique combination of building visited for every student?
So far my approach is to GROUP BY Date, Student ID, Building to sort them, then I am trying to Concatenate Rows with same Date and Student ID, but don't know to do this yet. In summary I am trying to achieve this table,

```
Date         |Student ID| Building 
2019-01-01   | 1        | A, B, C
2019-01-01   | 2        |  B, C
2019-01-01   | 3        |  B, C
2019-01-01   | 4        |    B
```

I am new to SQL(I'm using Google BigQuery for this), any tips is welcome

Answer (score 1):

You can use `string_agg()` or `array_agg()`:

```
select date, student_id, string_agg(building, ', ')
from t
group by date, student_id;
```

In BigQuery, though you would more typically use arrays:

```
select date, student_id, array_agg(building)
from t
group by date, student_id;
```

If you can have duplicates, then use `distinct` in the function.  If you want the rows in a specific ordering, use `order by`.  Something like:

```
select date, student_id, array_agg(distinct building order by building)
from t
group by date, student_id;
```

Comment: Not sure why, but I got "Unrecognized function array_agg" error. Do you know why it wouldn't work for me?

Comment: @Greedos . . . Be sure you are using standard SQL.

Comment: @Gordon can we achieve this without using an aggregate function. Dont know why there isnt any standard for such string aggregation like concat() in group by like we have sum() for numerics

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja . . . Of course there is a standard; it is called `listagg()`.  However, more databases tend to call the function `string_agg()`.  I'm not sure what you mean be not using an aggregation function.  You want to aggregate values, don't you?

Comment: I mean there isnt any standard Sql aggregate function for all databases for string concatenation like we have max() sum() etc. Likewise I thought if we can use via sunqueries with case statement without aggregate function to make it standard for almost all databases

Comment: As per your comment you mean to say listagg() works for all databases that supports sql? If thats the case, then its fine.

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja . . . No.  I mean that the SQL standard has `listagg()` as the string aggregation function.  More databases (I think) use `string_agg()`, though.  That is because Postgres uses `string_agg()` and a lot of databases are derived from Postgres.

Comment: ohkay @Gordon thanks mate for clearing out most of my questions. Actually, I have seen most of your answers and you have solved many queries via alternates so thats the reason I was asking you.

Answer (score -2):

You can get the desired result from STUFF function. Try the below.

```
SELECT Date, Student_ID, STUFF((
    SELECT ','+ cast(Building as nvarchar(max)) 
    FROM Tbl_Test t2
    WHERE t1.Date= t2.Date and  t1.Student_ID= t2.Student_ID
    ORDER BY Building
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'') AS Building
FROM Tbl_Test t1
GROUP BY t1.Date,t1.Student_ID
ORDER BY  t1.Date,t1.Student_ID
```